# Using bash command to download all gitlab projects at once

Tags: bash, gitlab, git-bash

I have more than 200 projects in my gitlab account. I want to download them all. I am using below command.

```
TOKEN="XXXXXXXXXX";
PREFIX="ssh_url_to_repo";
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" http://vrath.gitlabtest.com/api/v4/projects?per_page=100 |
    grep -o "\"$PREFIX\":[^ ,]\+" |
    awk -F ':' '{printf "ssh://"; for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf $i "/"; print $NF}' |
    xargs -L1 git clone
```

Above command is working fine but it only downloads 100 projects. I tried to do pagination but it is not working.

```
TOKEN="XXXXXXXXXX";
PREFIX="ssh_url_to_repo";
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" http://vrath.gitlabtest.com/api/v4/projects?per_page=100&page=2 |
    grep -o "\"$PREFIX\":[^ ,]\+" |
    awk -F ':' '{printf "ssh://"; for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf $i "/"; print $NF}' |
    xargs -L1 git clone
```

1. Can someone help me how to fix this? Is there any better way?
2. If you see this command: `grep -o "\"$PREFIX\":[^ ,]\+" | awk -F ':' '{printf "ssh://"; for (i=2; i<NF; i++) printf $i "/"; print $NF}'`

It will list down all the projects from "vrath.gitlabtest.com" but I can add some filers here? where it will list down project only for "vrath.gitlabtest/app1" or "vrath.gitlabtest/app2"

Answer (score 1):

Parse json with a json aware tool:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" http://vrath.gitlabtest.com/api/v4/projects?membership=true&per_page=100 | 
jq -r '.[].ssh_url_to_repo' | xargs -L1 git clone
```

The 'ssh_url_to_repo' json field returned by gitlab contains just what is says.

Note that, I think, without `membership=true` you are listing all repositories on your gitlab instance, not only those you belong to, so I added it above.

One time ago I have written a script that backups all my git repos from github, gitlab and aur.archlinux. You can check it out [here](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kamilscripts/blob/master/bin/gitsbackup.sh).

Comment: Thanks @Kamil for helping. I tried using jq. even ran the code you mentioned above but I am getting error  "fatal: You must specify a repository to clone." 

BTW I am running the command on git-bash

Comment: Then inspect it. Run without `xargs` see what it returns. Run `xargs -t` see what happens. Run git clone on one command see what happens. Run curl see what happens. Which command does return the "fatal" message?